# Error while using stastmodels' WLS: SVD did not converge

Tags: python, numpy, classification, linear-regression, training-data

I've written an algorithm for a cascaded boosting classifier using WLS (weighted least squares regression) in statsmodels, and have been able to successfully run it a few times. I used it with a few hundred images and all was fine.

However, I'm now using it to train a model from approximately 4000 images.
Now I'm getting the following error:

```
MKL ERROR: Parameter 4 was incorrect on entry to DLASCL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\app\Documents\Python Scripts\gbc_carclassify.py", line 95, in <module>
    gentlebooster.train(X_train,y_train,100)
  File "C:\Users\app\Documents\Python Scripts\gentleboost_c_class.py", line 103, in train
    temp_g = sm.WLS(y1, self.X, w).fit()  # Step 2(a)(ii)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py", line 127, in fit
    self.pinv_wexog = pinv_wexog = np.linalg.pinv(self.wexog)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1574, in pinv
    u, s, vt = svd(a, 0)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1323, in svd
    raise LinAlgError('SVD did not converge')
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

What could be the reason? I haven't seen this message before:

```
MKL ERROR: Parameter 4 was incorrect on entry to DLASCL.
```

It appears that the error was caused by this line:

```
 temp_g = sm.WLS(y1, self.X, w).fit()
```

Comment: Does [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/299717) help?

Comment: The most common case for `numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge` are nans (or infs) in the data. Which statsmodels version are you using? Check your w, X and wexog for nans. If it's not nans, then please report it on the statsmodels issue tracker on github.

Comment: In this line:  `temp_g = sm.WLS(y1, self.X, w).fit()`, I have found nans in `y1` (endog). Does that make a difference?

Comment: how can i check which statsmodels version I'm using? I'm running python on anaconda's spyder.

Comment: `import statsmodels; statsmodels.__version__`

Comment: nans in y1 (endog) shouldn't cause an error in this part `pinv(wexog)`, it should only create nans later on in the results. Try `mod = sm.WLS(y1, self.X, w); np.isfinite(mod.wexog).all()`

Comment: Okay I've stepped through the data carefully, `w` and `self.X` do not have NaNs. But `y1` has a few. The result is that when I do `temp_g = sm.WLS(y1, self.X, w).fit()` and then `print temp_g.params`, then `temp_g.params` is made up entirely of NaNs.